# Selenium: "Unable to find session with ID" after a few minutes of idling

Tags: python, selenium

I started a Docker container with:
`docker run -d --shm-size="4g" --hostname selenium_firefox selenium/standalone-firefox`

In another container with Python:

```
...
>>> driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://" +selenium_host+":4444/w
d/hub", desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, keep_alive=True)      
                                                                             
>>> driver.title                                                                
''                                                                              
>>> driver.title                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdri
ver.py", line 447, in title                                                     
    resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)                                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdri
ver.py", line 424, in execute                                                   
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorh
andler.py", line 247, in check_response                                         
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)                          
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to execute reques
t for an existing session: Unable to find session with ID: 5c619451-8361-4ec9-9b
7e-58b7afac15ff                                                                 
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'                            
System info: host: 'selenium_firefox', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-89-generic', java.version: '11.0.13'            
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The first `driver.title` I ran it immediately after creating the remote webdriver.

Then I waited for some time (around 15 minutes) and ran `driver.title` again, and it seem that the Python console has lost connection to the corresponding browser.

Why does this happen and how do I avoid it? It doesn't happen if I don't use a remote webdriver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Option 1: Override Docker Selenium Grid default session timeout***

From docker/selenium documentation:

> Grid has a default session timeout of 300 seconds, where the session can be on a stale state until it is killed. You can use SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT to overwrite that value in seconds.

```
docker run -d -e SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=1000 --shm-size="4g" --hostname selenium_firefox selenium/standalone-firefox
```

***Option 2: Ping your session once in 60 (any < 300) seconds***

You may execute some driver command in a loop during the idle time

```
for x in range(15):
    time.sleep(60)
    driver.current_url
```

---

**Reference**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#grid-url-and-session-timeout