# Selenium/Fitnesse loses session during test (

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, fitnesse

I'm using Fitnesse to create tests. When I run them in de webbased tool they succeed. When run via Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server I get the following error, although sometimes it seems to run normal at the same point but in a different testcase.

```html
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to execute request for an existing session: Unable to find session with ID: <session-id>
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: 'G-WPTAPP-01', ip: '<ip>', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'G-WPTAPP-01', ip: '<ip>', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [<session-id>, findElements {using=css selector, value=#mask}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: msedge, browserVersion: 102.0.1245.44, javascriptEnabled: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64446}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 102.0.1245.44 (72efbf98e0b4..., userDataDir: D:\Users\svc_g-wptapp-01\Ap...}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://<ip>:4444/sessi..., se:cdpVersion: 102.0.1245.44, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: <session-id>
```

I have already tried updating the edgedriver and extending the grid session-timeout but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Here's [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794535/selenium-unable-to-find-session-with-id-after-a-few-minutes-of-idling) as yours. Maybe you can get some inspiration from it. Also, I think this error is similar to Invalid session ID. You can take a look at [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID). So make sure you haven't quit the driver if you want to use the driver again.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried expanding the grid session timeout. It didn't work. And the test fails halfway through, so nog explicit browser quit has occurred...

Comment: Please make sure you match the Edge browser with the same version of Edge driver. Besides, I notice that you say it only shows errors in TFS. Could you please provide the YAML pipeline definition for detailed information? You can remove your in-private information when providing the information.